# using django-registration form instead of own

Tags: python, django, forms, django-registration

So I am using `django-registration` for email activation and the like. I defined my form and am calling to it properly however for some reason it is using the base form out of `django-registration` instead of my own. I have absolutely no clue as to why this is happening, any thoughts?

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render, render_to_response
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
from django.template.context_processors import csrf
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from .forms import UserForm


def register(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UserForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/accounts/register/complete')

    else:
        form = UserForm()
        token = {}
        token.update(csrf(request))
        token['form'] = form

    return render('registration/registration_form.html', token)

def registration_complete(request):
    return render('registration/registration_complete.html')
```

urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import include, url
from django.contrib import admin
from main import views

urlpatterns = [

    # Registration URLs
    url(r'^accounts/', include('registration.backends.hmac.urls')),
    url(r'^accounts/register/$', views.register, name='register'),
    url(r'^accounts/register/complete/$', views.registration_complete, name='registration_complete'),

    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),
    url(r'^contact/$', views.contact, name='contact'),
    url(r'^login/$', views.login, name='login'),
    url(r'^register/$', views.register, name='register'),
    url(r'^profile/$', views.profile, name='profile'),
    url(r'^blog/$', views.blog, name='blog'),
```

forms.py

```
from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm
from django.utils.translation import gettext as _
from registration.forms import RegistrationFormUniqueEmail, RegistrationForm

class UserForm(UserCreationForm):

    email = forms.EmailField(required=True)
    first_name = forms.CharField(label=_("Firstname"), required=False)
    last_name = forms.CharField(label=_("Lastname"),  required=False)

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('username', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'email', 'password1', 'password2')

    def save(self, commit=True):
        user = super(UserForm, self).save(commit=False)
        user.first_name = self.cleaned_data['first_name']
        user.last_name = self.cleaned_data['last_name']
        user.email = self.cleaned_data['email']

        if commit:
            user.save()

        return user
```

template

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% block title %}Register{% endblock %}
{% block content %}

  <h2>Registration</h2>

  <form action="/accounts/register/" method="post">{% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.as_p }}
  <input type="submit" value="Register" />

  </form>

{% endblock %}
```

Comment: You need to subclass `UserForm(RegistrationForm):` not `UserForm(UserCreationForm):`

Comment: I thought that was the case as well, but it did not change anything.

Comment: What do you expect? What fields?

Comment: The fields are irrelevant, I can add the fields into the `forms.py` of `django-registration` and get the desired effect that way if I absolutely need to. The bigger issue here is that for some reason the application is not using my form at all and instead automatically using the `forms.py` of `django-registration` even though I am telling it to use mine.

Comment: How do you know that? What is desired output and what you get?

Comment: I know because I tested by commenting out the entire form I had created and it still persisted. I then went to the `forms.py` in `django-registration` and added in the `first_name` and `last_name` fields into the `RegistrationForm` class and then requested it in my browser and saw the changes take effect. No matter what I change in my `UserForm` class within my `forms.py` no change takes effect.

Comment: Try to change the order of urls: put `url(r'^accounts/', include('registration.backends.hmac.urls')),` on 3rd place after your urls.

Comment: That definitely did something, but now I am getting this error:  django.template.exceptions.TemplateDoesNotExist: {'form': <UserForm bound=False, valid=Unknown, fields=(username;first_name;last_name;email;password1;password2)>, 'csrf_token': <SimpleLazyObject: <function csrf.<locals>._get_val at 0x11083b378>>}

Comment: Check if you got template there, of if your path is correct, maybe it's `'templates/registration/registration_form.html'`

Comment: I figured out why I was getting that error, the first to lines in `urls.py` were completely unnecessary and creating issues. I removed them and now I am back at my original issue.

Comment: C'mon, you dont need to remove those urls. If you want your custom handling _register_ process, then you need to keep them(before declaring urls from package). The error that you were getting with template, happened because you don't have template in `'registration/registration_form.html'` path. You need to have such. Or you need to change path(referencing to existing template that you have that renders your form)

Answer (score 1):

Since `urlpatterns` has that order:

```
url(r'^accounts/', include('registration.backends.hmac.urls')),
url(r'^accounts/register/$', views.register, name='register'),
url(r'^accounts/register/complete/$', views.registration_complete, name='registration_complete'),
```

Url from `url(r'^accounts/', include('registration.backends.hmac.urls')),` match your `/accounts/register/` url first, and don't get to your `views.register` view. So, to change that, you need to change the order, so that url patterns would be

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^accounts/register/$', views.register, name='register'),
    url(r'^accounts/register/complete/$', views.registration_complete, name='registration_complete'),
    url(r'^accounts/', include('registration.backends.hmac.urls')),
    ...
    ]
```